# Higher-spin ising model optimization problem

Tags: ising-model, spin-models

Ising model is used as an Ising machine for solving the combinatorial optimization problems.

The spin of the Ising machine for this application is normally 1/2.

But I wonder if there is any optimization problems that are targeted to be solved using higher-spin (such as S=1, 3/2 etc.) Ising model do exist (such as ternary, quaternary problems).

Comment: You can look at "Potts machines optimization" on Internet. It will give you a starting point.

Comment: Are you referring classical or quantum Ising?

Comment: Quantum Ising model, but I think there is no difference between quantum and classic.